# Android Service onBind required?

Tags: android, kotlin, service

From the android docs:

> Although you usually implement either onBind() or onStartCommand(),
>   it's sometimes necessary to implement both. For example, a music
>   player might find it useful to allow its service to run indefinitely
>   and also provide binding. This way, an activity can start the service
>   to play some music and the music continues to play even if the user
>   leaves the application. Then, when the user returns to the
>   application, the activity can bind to the service to regain control of
>   playback. [source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services)

In the service implementation i get from `import android.app.Service`, onBind in abstract.`[compileSdkVersion 28]`

Am i missing something or is the documentation simply wrong with the Statement that i *may* implement onBind?

Comment: can you explain what you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the documentation for `onBind`, It says

> Return the communication channel to the service. May return null if clients can not bind to the service. The returned IBinder is usually for a complex interface that has been described using aidl. [Check Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onBind(android.content.Intent))

So Yes, You have to override `onBind`.

As per your documentation ref given in the question,

> Although you usually implement either onBind() or onStartCommand(), it's sometimes necessary to implement both.

So, This is not about overriding, This is about whether you have to provide actual implementation or not.